# Autolayout clears my button text

Tags: ios6, interface-builder, storyboard, autolayout

Every time I try to use autolayout the button text on one row of my button becomes crammed until its no longer visible.

I dont know what to do to fix this, I tried removing the offending buttons and adding them again but that usually migrates the problem to another row.

here is what it looks like in interface builder.

[image]

and here is what it looks like when run on the device.

[image]

This is extremely frustrating and I have found no information about it. As if Im the only person this is affecting.

If anyone has any insights into this, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just dropping your items into the view is no longer an option.

I had to remove all my buttons, and lay them out one at a time promoting all my constraints to user constraints along the way.

I created the first item and promoted width and height. then promoted the connections to the superview.

I then copied that button (and its held constraints of width and height) and connected it to the button to the left as well as the top.

Then I connected the next button completing the full row.

After I had a row, I copied the row and connected it to the bottom of the row above it and so on until all my items were complete.

I spent quite a while trying to get rid of random baseline connections such as button 7 to button 3. The automatically selected constraints are not only completely inaccurate and un-usable. they are a pain to get rid of as well.

Clearly the autolayout will force you to build your interface with much more care in mind. Which will not be a bad thing, but does hamper rapid development as you have to be extremely careful not to let the interface builder attach constrains you dont want.

Answer (score 1):

Auto Layout takes some time to get used too. Aleksandar Vacic answered this question in a different post.

> I assume that you have created one button, then copied across the row and then copied the rows down. When you do that, one of the auto-layout constraints that's set is "Baseline alignment" between the buttons.
>
> So select the problematic button and check to see if you have this constraint. If you do, select it, upgrade to user-defined and delete it. All
> magically works afterwards.

Source: [UIButton not showing the text in iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835134/uibutton-not-showing-the-text-in-ios6)